# Can't update angular view from legacy code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing the following problem

1. broadcast event from legacy code.
2. use $scope.$on for getting the event.
3. the event call api method that resolve new data.
4. update the view result in - nothing happens.

I used all the technique i was able to find:

1. $scope.$apply - was resulted in $digest is already in progress
2. used $timeout function, nothing happens
3. used scope apply inside $timeout - nothing happens.

I'm not sure what to do if someone can help i appreciate it.

this is the code:

```
var injector;
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

on javascript legacy code:

```
function sendRefresh()
{
    injector.invoke(['CommonService', function(CommonService){
        CommonService.broadcast_from_legacy('refresh-content');
    }]);
}
```

on controller:

```
$scope.$on('refresh-content',
            function () {
                $scope.refresh_data(true);

            });

$scope.refresh_data = function()
        {
            CommonService.get_homepage_from_server().then(function(result_data){

                $scope.messages = result_data.messages;
            });
        };
```

i see the function is getting called, the new data arrived, but the view is not refreshed.

I tried also:

```
 $scope.refresh_data = function(shouldApply)
        {
            CommonService.get_homepage_from_server().then(function(result_data){

                if (shouldApply == true)
                {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function(){
                            $scope.messages = null;
                        });
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.messages = result_data.messages;
                }
            });
        };
```

And :

```
  $scope.refresh_data = function()
    {
        CommonService.get_homepage_from_server().then(function(result_data){
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.messages = result_data.messages[0];
            });
        });
        };
```

but i get the same result.

Thanks

Comment: What does result_data look like if you console.log it?

Comment: @Patrick result data is an array of objects, but it can be anything you like, it doesn't matter even if i set it to null nothing happens, and the view should disapear if i'm setting it to null somewhere else in code.